# Что такое CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) и зачем они нужны?

Tags: sql, char

Вижу в скрипте такое значение CHAR(13) + CHAR(10). Вообще скрипт для того, чтобы вставить в таблицу три значения. И вот эти CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) вставлены в скрипт не 3, а 4 раза, то есть обступают значения со всех сторон.

Можете рассказать, что это такое и зачем нужно?

Если будете употреблять слово каретка, то, пожалуйста, уточните, что это значит в sql.

Comment: И всё-равно это "возврат каретки" и "перевод строки". Исторически это такие символы для перевода строки, используются парой в каких-то ОС, а в каких-то достаточно одного символа.

Comment: Символы с кодами 13 и 10 просто создают перенос строки в тексте, вот и всё

Answer (score 7):

`char(13)` - это carriage return (возврат каретки) - проще говоря символ `return/ввод`

`char(10)` - это line feed (новая строка)

**Update**

*Каретка* - это был такой в механизм в пишущей машинке, в котором располагался лист бумаги, на которой печатали, на фото это сверху бандура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для перевода каретки была такая клавиша называлась *возврат каретки* или *ВК*, по английски *CR* - carriage return (на фото ее роль играет огромный крюк слева вверху)

Исторически раньше печатали все на пишмашинке включая код для компутеров с тех пор это осталось. Сейчас ее роль выполняет клавиша *ENTER/RETURN/ВВОД*

*LineFeed* - новая строка, кстати ее роль на фото выполняет черный валик справа, машинистка вручную крутила ее, чтобы перевести новую строку (в зависимости от продвинутости машинки LF иногда надо было переводить вручную, а иногда он был совмещен с CR). Этот анахронизм сохранился до сих пор. В разных операционных системах новая строка трактуется разными наборами символов:

1. Windows - CR+LF
2. Unix/Linux - LF
3. MacOS - CR

P.S. Неужели я это все написал - чувствую себя динозавром :)

Comment: все еще непонятно: 
- что такое каретка
- почему их 4 на три значения
- почему нельзя написать через запятую
- есть ли еще какие-то символы, которые имеют специальное значение? где про это почитать?

Comment: @kkorolyova Про спецсимволы начните отсюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B Каретка - потому что раньше печатающие устройства были механические, у них была каретка. Зачем именно в вашем случае столько переводов строки - это надо смотреть конкретный кейс, о чём речь вообще.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: @kkorolyova видимо нужно 4 переноса строки, без примера скрипта никто не скажет вам точно для чего это используется. `Возвра́т каре́тки` — управляющий символ, управляющий символ - это символ без графического представления. Через `char` можно напечатать практически любой символ, как текстовые, так и управляющий, подробнее можно прогуглить > "Таблица символов ASCII-Char"